# Deciphering Air Europe booking codes

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings

I have an Air Europe ticket with "fare basis" code PLYR7L. I'd like to know what my flexibility and options are with regards to changes/cancellations etc. However, I can not find what this code means. Does someone know how to decipher this code?

Comment: What are the origin, destination, and travel dates?

Comment: [Decoding airline fare basis codes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/84825/903)

Answer (score 2):

The code itself has no standard structure, except the first letter which is the booking class (used to determine availability buckets and service levels), each airline make up their own codes which may or may not have a structure.

For instance the `7` probably means there’s either a 7-day minimum stay (for a return fare) or a 7-day minimum advance purchase, but it could mean anything else they want.

You have to lookup the specific fare code for that specific airline to find out the rules.

Usually the simplest option for passengers is just to check their receipt/confirmation or e-ticket, or to log into the “manage my booking” section of the airline’s website.

Otherwise you can use a tool such as [Expertflyer](https://expertflyer.com) to look up fare rules (it’s a subscription-based service but there’s a free trial). Note that fare rules in standard GDS format are not always very easy to understand and can easily be misinterpreted if you are not used to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the general concept but am particularly interested in knowing MY booking code. Really a shame that there is no transparency on this. My booking details do not disclose anything, nothing in my e-mail, and nothing to be found when I manage my booking through Air Europa. Shame it requires a paid service. But thanks for the insights.

Comment: With your ticket receipt, you should have a short description of the tariff (and conditions). What you need are that description and not the code (but with few tickets you may be able to find some rules between the two)

Comment: I've read the emails three times but all it explains are conditions with regards to luggage and that's it. They refer to the website for other policies but that doesn't tell me what applies to MY ticket, only the general booking rules.

Comment: @BlueLizard https://www.aireuropa.com/fr/en/aea/travel-information/terms-and-conditions/booking-conditions says  there are three types of economy fares: lite, standard and flex, and details the change/cancellation rules for each. Surely somewhere it tells you which of the three your ticket is? What happens if you manage your booking and try to cancel or change a flight? Surely it will tell you if it’s allowed or not and what the cost is, isn’t it the case?

Comment: Can’t find that specific fare rule without the origin/destination and dates, but it looks like fare ending with “L” are Lite fares. Detailed rules available here: https://www.aireuropa.com/fr/en/aea/aexperience/our-fares so basically no cancellations, changes with a penalty + fare difference.